# How can I import a .txt file containing a matrix of numbers and work with its columns?

Tags: import, list-manipulation

I want to import a text file which has two columns. Then I want to assign one column to an array alpha[i].

Using the following command assigns the whole file to t[i].

```
t[i_] := Import["aru.txt"]
```

How will I extract one column from this array?

Edit: The file looks like this-

```
2.040816326530612e-8        3.1415925897597883
0.00030671792055962676      3.1406333410803806
0.0006134154329559882       3.1396740924018594
0.0012268104577487112       3.137755595047072
0.002453600507334157        3.13391860034367
```

Note- This is a text file (not to confuse with a csv file). The file is without comma and brackets.

Edit-2:

As the file format was little confusing so I removed the brackets and only used the comma's so that it is readable. It is a text file and not a csv file. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Hi, Aru :) Could you give an example of the file? Just a few lines would do.

Comment: It depends somewhat on the file. In good cases, `Import["aru.txt", "Table"][[All, i]]` should read only the `i`-th column.

Comment: Thanks, Henrik Schumacher. It works for me.

Comment: Please clarify: does the file look like what you say, or is it without comma and brackets?

Comment: @Roman the file looks like what I said. The file is without comma and brackets. I used comma's and brackets because it was difficult to read.  The file is a text file with two columns and without comma and brackets.

Comment: like what I edited?

Comment: @Aru You're welcome.

Comment: @Roman, Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

import the file:

```
T = Import["aru.txt", "Table"];
```

assign elements to `α`:

```
MapIndexed[(α[#2[[1]]] = #1[[2]]) &, T];
```

check:

```
?α
```

should give a list of assigned values `α[1]=...`, `α[2]=...` etc.

Note however that this `α` is not an array, but a function. If you want an array, you can use

```
α = T[[All, 2]];
```

and access the elements with `α[[1]]`, `α[[2]]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

To import data, I prefer to use an OS independent full path name, so I would do the import like this:

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "aru.txt"}];
data = Import[path, "Table"];
```

To extract the columns and assign them to variables for further use, you could write something like this

```
Module[{col1, col2},
  col1 = data[[All, 1]];
  col2 = data[[All, 2]];
  Transpose[{col1, col2}] == data]
```

> `True`

which just a way of checking that transposing the columns of a matrix gives back the original matrix.

However, in Mathematica, variables can often be dispensed with. Consider

```
Transpose[data] == {data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]}
```

which checks the inverse of the previous computation; i.e., the transpose pf a matrix is an array of it columns. This means that you could also write

```
{col1, col2} =  Transpose[data];
```

In Wolfram Language there usually many ways to make the same computation. It us a very rich and flexible programming language.